# How to get path to res.drawable folder to copy a file?

Tags: java, android

I am writing my app in `AndroidStudio`, I got gif file in my `drawable/gifs` folder and I wish to copy that file to `MediaStore.Images.Media` folder after clicking a button.

Currently I can't get my gif path even when using some answers posted.
The path I've tried using is
`android.resource://com.example.bartoszwolski.cluainkeyboard/drawable/gifs/my.gif`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use Uri:

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your_packagename/" + R.drawable.your_image_id);
```

and:

```
new File(fileUri.getPath());
```

Comment: Is there an update to this? Is there a constant or another way to get "android.resource://your_packagename/" as opposed to hard coding it?

Comment: @lcj: "android.resource://" + Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName + "/" + Resource.Drawable.your_image_id);