# Convert Drawable path to URI

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-glide

I have an image in my `@drawable/myimage.jpg` of which I would like to load on my `ImageView` through Glide. Glide however, only accepts Uri's to load the actual image to the ImageView. 
Here's the code:

```
uriImage  =   Uri.parse("@drawable/myimage.jpg");


//LOADS IMAGES USING GLIDE
Glide.with(AboutActivity.this).load(uriImage).into(imgView);
```

It somewhat doesn't work. Is there any work-arounds this? 

Sorry for being naive, I just started using Android Studio again :)

Comment: ```Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.myimage).into(imageView);``` Does this help? Check this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/29987915/726625

Comment: @sha Much more simpler answer! Thanks! :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get path to res.drawable folder to copy a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045988/how-to-get-path-to-res-drawable-folder-to-copy-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
String imageUrl = getURLForResource(R.drawable.personIcon);
// Load image
 Glide.with(patientProfileImageView.getContext())
      .load(imageUrl)
      .into(patientProfileImageView);
```

it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this!

```
Glide.with(AboutActivity.this).load(R.drawable.resouce_name).into(imgView);
```